# Error using end=" " within a function call

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code works to send a message to a user:

```
mud.send_message(id, rooms[self.current_room]["desc"])
```

In one part of the game code, I don't want to start on a new line so I try:

```
mud.send_message(id, rooms[self.current_room]["desc"], end=" ")
mud.send_message(id, "This starts on the same line as the code above.")
```

This of course raises an error that the third variable (end=" ") is not welcome here. How can I start the second message on the same line?

Extra info if needed:

```
def send_message(self, to, message):
    self._attempt_send(to, message+"\n\r")
```

Comment: Well, if you want to have an `end` parameter, why don't you add it to the `send_message` function, and use it to control whether `\n\r` is added or not?

Comment: Is the `send_message` function part of the code that you wrote yourself? If not, where did you get the code, and *what does the documentation say*?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Because I want this to happen at specific places, not on every message.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The documentation simply states:
"we make sure to put a newline on the end so the client receives the message on its own line", which is fine in most cases.

Comment: @mkrieger1 What I meant was that 99% of the time, I want the new line. There are few instances that I don't want the new line so manually adding the \n in the 99% of those cases would be inefficient for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `end` parameter that you have in mind is *specific to* the built-in `print` function; other things that output text will *not* necessarily support it.

If `send_message` is your own code, then you could modify it not to add the newline automatically - or even to implement the `end` parameter (I can add details if desired).

If `send_message` is in someone else's library, then *in general* you should check the documentation for that library first and see what is recommended.

However, for a case as simple as this one, the obvious thing to do is just prepare a single line of text for output, so that only one `send_message` call is made.

You can do this for example with string formatting:

```
# Python 3.6 and later
mud.send_message(id, f'{rooms[self.current_room]["desc"]} This is on the same line.')
# Earlier 3.x, before the introduction of f-strings
mud.send_message(id, '{} This is on the same line.'.format(rooms[self.current_room]["desc"]))
```

Comment: Beautiful, this was the syntax I couldn't figure out. See above as to why I don't want to add it to every message, i.e. the main send_message code.

Answer (score -1):

Since `send_message` always concatenates `'\n\r'` to any `message` you pass to it, you can call `_attempt_send` instead:

```
mud._attempt_send(id, rooms[self.current_room]["desc"] + " ")
```

Comment: -1: While this would work, the leading `_` on this method name strongly indicates it is not intended to be called directly. (It seems likely that OP has gone to examine the code of a third-party library.)